# HTML/CSS Fixed Menu Bug - FIXED

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

I've been having a problem with a new website theme I'm creating, this didn't occur to me before until I scrolled down. 
Here is the problem. I created a fixed menu (which will stick to the top of the page wherever you are on the page). When you scroll down, the menu goes UNDER the content box instead. I couldn't find a solution to this either. I'm not a professional html or css web developer anyway.

Source:

File: Header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface/css/style.css">


</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="interface/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


$('a').mouseout(function() {
$(this).stop().animate({
    opacity:'0.7'
  });
});
$('a').mouseover(function() {
$(this).stop().animate({
    opacity:'1'
  });
});

$('#header-container > a').mouseout(function() {
$(this).stop().animate({
    opacity:'0.7'
  });
});
$('#header-container > a').mouseover(function() {
$(this).stop().animate({
    opacity:'1'
  });
});


});
</script>
<div id="header-container">
<div id="header-image" align="center"><a href="#"><img src="interface/images/interface/header.png" title="Home"></a></div>

<div id="header-social">
<a id="icon" href="#"><img src="interface/images/icons/facebook.png" title="Facebook"></a>
<a id="icon" href="#"><img src="interface/images/icons/twitter.png" title="Twitter"></a>
<a id="icon" href="#"><img src="interface/images/icons/blog.png" title="Blog"></a>
</div>

<div id="header-bottom"></div>
<div id="menu">

<ul><a class="text" href="#" title="">Home</a></ul>
<ul><a class="text" href="#" title="">About</a></ul>
<ul><a class="text" href="#" title="">Articles</a></ul>
<ul><a class="text" href="#" title="">Videos</a></ul>
<ul><a class="text" href="#" title="">Tutorials</a></ul>
<ul><a class="text" href="#" title="">Downloads</a></ul>
<ul><a class="text" href="#" title="">Contact</a></ul>
<ul><a class="text" href="#" title="">Help</a></ul>

</div>
</div>

<body>
<div id="main-container">
```

File: index.php

```
    <div id="container">
<div id="content-container">
lorem ipsum
</div>
</div>
```

File: Footer.php

```
<!--Footer Container-->
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

The CSS Styles: style.css:

```
@font-face { font-family: myriad; src: url('../font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF'); }

/*HTML Ententites*/

html{
    margin:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: myriad;
    color: white;
}
body{
    background:white;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
/*Containers*/
#header-container{
    background:#202020;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 100px;
}
#header-bottom{
height: 1px;
width: auto;
background:#8A8A8A;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
box-shadow: 0 0 50px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

#header-image{
    position: absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .7;
}
#header-social{
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:50px;
}
#header-social > #icon{
    opacity: .7;
}
#header-social > #icon:hover{
    background: url('../images/icons/icon-hover.png') no-repeat;
    opacity: 1;
}

#main-container{
    background:#454545;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -8px;
    height: 1500px;
}

#menu{
position: fixed;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 50px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);

}
#menu > ul{
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(10,174,254,.8);
    height:40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
    width: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: myriad;
}
#menu > ul:hover{
    background: rgba(10,174,254,1);
}
#menu > ul > .text{
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: .7;

}

#container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 500px;
    left: 10px;
    margin-top:250px;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
#content-container{
    background:#646464;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-bottom:3px solid #2B312D;
    border-left:3px solid #2B312D;
    border-right:3px solid #2B312D;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
#content-header{

}
```

I suppose the problem must be somewhere in my CSS for the menu. I don't think it's layered correctly in the html, but again, I suck at layering, I'm still learning. :)
Thanks in advance.

[LIVE VIEW](http://nighthawk1037.comze.com/reigel)
Scroll down over the content box.

Comment: There is no menu at that page. Chances are a z-index style statement will fix what ails you.

Comment: Sorry about that, I mixed up the ftp. I just re-uploaded it. Please a have a look again, thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `z-index` to 2.

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: @IrfanDahir Instead of changing the title of the question, could you mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to the answer? (Or a different answer, if another answers your question better.) This helps Stack Overflow to know that the question has been resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `z-index` in your *menu*.

**CSS**

```
#menu {
z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: I don't have over 99999 layers. :P But this works too. Thanks. :D

Comment: Just a note for future visitors: Setting the `z-index` to arbitrary values (such as `99999`) can lead to unmanageable stylesheets in the long run. Instead, it's a good idea to come up with a system for how you assign `z-index` (avoiding it whenever possible), so you don't accidentally cover up an element later (or fail to cover it up) because you don't have the list of all `z-index`s used in your application.